# Custom strongly typed helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

I´m getting errors using my custom helpers:

CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments

Here is the view code:

```
@Html.BsLookUp(Model => Model.FieldId, Model.FieldDescription)
```

And the helper:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString BsLookUp<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string initialText)
    {
        string fieldName= ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        sb.AppendFormat("<input type='text' name='{0}' value='{1}'/>", campo, initialText);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

if I pass a string directly in my view this works:

```
@Html.BsLookUp(Model => Model.HandleMotivoglosa, "any text here..")
```

Comment: Is `Model.FieldDescription` a string?

Comment: Yes, it is. That´s strange isn't it?

Comment: Your question is a bit incomplete. You didn't post the relevant parts of Model. And are there overloads for this helper method? And the view is missing too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you noticed:

```
@Html.BsLookUp(Model => Model.FieldId, Model.FieldDescription)
//             ^        ^              ^
//             |        |              |
//             |        |              +- here, Model is a variable already defined
//             |        |
//             +--------+- here, Model is (supposed to be) a new variable
```

The error seems quite obscure, but try changing your code to:

```
@Html.BsLookUp(m => m.FieldId, Model.FieldDescription)
```